# Content Scrolls over image

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have an image which isn't set as the background, but takes up the entire width and almost all of the height. I want this image to remain in it's position and as the user scrolls, the content below scrolls over the top of the image.

I tried using:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: -1; /* Or another value */
```

but neither or together worked.

What I have without the position or z-index applied: https://jsfiddle.net/hhcvmrfx/

**I want the div container to appear under the image and only overlap the image when the user scrolls.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overlap the container below only when the user scrolls down, you'll need to set a padding-top value, to your parent `.container`, equal to or less than the height of the fixed image in question.
Then apply your background colour to the nested `div` element instead.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Images */
#head-banner-img {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #222222;
  position: fixed;
}

/* Container Content */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-top: 947px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.container > div {
    background: #2c2c2c;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.thestoryboardz.com/images/background.jpg" alt="Munch Banner" id="head-banner-img">
    <div class="container">
      <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the div's image as a background image instead and give it:

```
background-attachment: fixed
```